# Error void-variable on function name

Tags: debugging, variables, quote

What is the difference between the two functions `func1` and `func2`?

```
(defun func1 (arg)
  (if (listp arg)
      (mapcar (lambda (x) (func1 x)) arg)
    arg))

(func1 (list 1 2 3))

(defun func2 (arg)
  (if (listp arg)
      (mapcar func2 arg)
    arg))

(func2 (list 1 2 3))
```

`func1` works fine, but `func2` throws `void-variable func2`. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Short Answer

Replace `func2` with `#'func2`:

```
(defun func2 (arg)
  (if (listp arg)
      (mapcar #'func2 arg)
    arg))
```

## Explanation

[Emacs Lisp is a lisp-2 (like Common Lisp), not lisp-1 (unlike, say, Scheme)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781).

I.e., every symbol in ELisp has a

- "value cell": accessed by `symbol-value`, tested by `boundp`, and used by the compiler when the symbol is in the "variable" position, i.e., *not* as the first element of a list to be evaluated - like your use of `func2`.
- "function cell": accessed by `symbol-function`, tested by `fboundp`, and used by the compiler when the symbol is in the "function" position, i.e., the first element of a list to be evaluated - like your use of `func1`.

Since `func2` is in variable position and it has a function binding and not a variable binding, you are getting the `void variable` error. You need to tell the compiler to use the function value instead of the variable value, and this is accomplished by prefixing it with `#'` (you *can* use the [ordinary quote `'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701698/850781) instead too, but it is a bad idea because it makes code less readable and self-documenting).

See also [Why use #' before function arguments in emacs-lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18390586/850781)

Comment: Note that sharp-quoting is *not* required and a regular quote will do fine.

Comment: @wasamasa: yes you can, but no you should NOT. code readability matters!

Comment: @sds But the Emacs manual does not do it either: [mapcar](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html)

Comment: @ceving: this is a hold-over from ancient times; please report it as a bug.