# Evaluate allows for combinations whose operators are compound expressions

Tags: functions, variables, funcall

I find the amazing power of scheme in [sicp](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.4)

> Exercise 1.4.  Observe that our model of evaluation allows for
>   combinations whose operators are compound expressions. Use this
>   observation to describe the behavior of the following procedure:

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define (a-plus-abs-b a b)
  ((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
(a-plus-abs-b 9 4)
 #+END_SRC

 #+RESULTS:
 : 13
```

Try to rewrite it as

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(defun a-plus-abs-b(a b)
  ((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
(a-plus-abs-b 9 4)
#+end_src
```

report error "invalid function"

Alternatively with

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(defun a-plus-abs-b(a b)
  (funcall (if (> b 0) + -) a b))
(a-plus-abs-b 9 4)
#+end_src
```

Error reported as

```
funcall: Symbol’s value as variable is void: +
```

How could write it correctly in elisp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error void-variable in mapcar](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/error-void-variable-in-mapcar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`funcall` takes a function as its first argument, so you need
`if` to return a function symbol.  You can do that by
sharp-quoting its return value:

```
(defun a-plus-abs-b (a b)
  (funcall (if (> b 0) #'+ #'-) a b))

(a-plus-abs-b 9 4)                  ; => 13
```

Elisp is a Lisp-2, which means each symbol can have a function
value and a variable value.  When you don't quote the return
value of `if`, you're asking it to return the variable value of
`+` or `-`, which you could actually do if you want to:

```
(setq - "testing")
(- 1 1)                                 ; => 0
-                                       ; => "testing"
(+ 1 1)                                 ; => 2
+                                       ; => void variable "+"
```

See:

- [When should sharp quotes be used?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35988/253)
- [Get in the habit of using sharp quote](https://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html)

Comment: It's more like a brain teaser. So function is not named as the first-class citizen in elisp?

Comment: It is a first-class citizen.  It's just that symbols can hold a function and variable value.  See this SO thread: [What is the difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2)